# How to use RevoScaleR lib in Visual Studio with R Tools?

Tags: r, sql-server, visual-studio, data-science, microsoft-r

I have Visual Studio Professional 2017 with R Tools installed and Microsoft R Open as a default interpreter.
However, when I want to use function RxInSqlServer, I'm getting the error:

> "package ‘RevoScaleR’ is not available (for R version 3.4.3)"

I've tried

```
#install.packages('RevoScaleR')
```

but have thought RevoScaleR should be included in Microsoft R Open by default.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RevoScaleR is not available in Microsoft R Open. It is available in Microsoft ML Services, SQL Server In-Database Analytics, and Microsoft R Client.